How to update LinearProgressIndicator in android
I have added LinearProgressIndicator in xml i.e com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator which I need to set value as soon as there's change in values, Other values update correctly but LPI doesn't seem to update value. It works if I set a static value to it rather than calculated one.
private fun updateDashboard(binding: ActivityMainBinding) {
    val totalAmount = transactions.sumOf { it.amount }
    val budgetAmount = transactions.filter { it.amount > 0 }.sumOf { it.amount }
    val expenseAmount = totalAmount - budgetAmount
    val spentPercent = ((expenseAmount / budgetAmount) * 100)

    binding.apply {
        "₹ %.2f".format(totalAmount).also { balanceTV.text = it }
        "₹ %.2f".format(budgetAmount).also { budgetTV.text = it }
        "₹ %.2f".format(abs(expenseAmount)).also { expenseTV.text = it }
        "%.0f%%".format(abs(spentPercent)).also { spentPercentTV.text = it }
        "₹ %.0f".format(budgetAmount).also { budgetTV2.text = it }
    }
    progressIndicator.setProgress(spentPercent.toInt(), true)
}


val spentPercent = abs((expenseAmount / budgetAmount) * 100) // converted to positive number

The bug was that the number was negative which I didn't pay attention for some reason.
